# grep command in bash script does not work as expected

Tags: bash

I'm from time to time check the syslog for the first and last line of a specific date.
The command i'm using is:
grep -a "Dec 23" messages-20221* | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' | cut -b19-30
(in the directory are the weekly copied messages files)

Now i tried to create a bash script, that takes the month as parameter and cycles trough the month.
So, on bash i enter:
user:~$ start_time Dec
and i expect to see smth like:

```
Dec  1 09:16
Dec  1 20:45
 :
Dec 30 09:27
Dec 30 14:52
```

The body of script reads like this:

```
search_month=$1" "
echo $search_month
for i in {1..31}
do
  if [[ $i -lt 10 ]]
  then
    search_date=$search_month" "$i
  else
    search_date=$search_month$i
  fi
  echo $search_date
    grep -a \"$search_date\" /root/backup/messages-2022* | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' | cut -b19-30
done
```

First issue is, that "search_date=$search_month" "$i" does not result in month, two blanks, day,
but only only blank in between ("Dec  1" vs "Dec 1"). I already tried:

```
var="  "
search_date=$search_month" "$i
```

or

```
search_date="$search_month"" ""$i"
```

but the search_date has only one blank.

Second issue is, that the grep command does not work as expected.
Instead of

```
grep -a "Dec  1" /root/backup/messages-2022* | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' | cut -b19-30
```

i get the message:

```
Dec 1
grep: 1": No such file or directory
```

Also, /root/backup/messages-2022* changes into ges-2022

Already googled how to use grep with wildcards in a bash script, but didn't find anything helpful.
Consulting several tutorial pages also didn't bring the break through.

Comment: For the second issue, you don't most likely don't need to escape those quotes (`\"$search_date\"`) in the last line of the loop.

Comment: Your quoting is wrong, especially in `echo $search_date` (should be `echo "$search_date"`) and `grep -a \"$search_date\" ...` (should be`grep -a "$search_date" ...`). In general, variable references should be inside non-escaped double-quotes. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point these (and some other problems) out, although it misunderstands how to fix the problem in the `sed` command.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. They solved my issue.
The issue with seeing "ges-2022" was result of **cut** command using wrong parameter.
When running the **grep** command on CLI the files without the path, while in the script they came with full_path_to_file.